# Confusion about ActiveRecord relation exists? method, especially with limit and offset

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am running Rails 3.2.8 and ruby 1.9.3p194.

I'm trying to better understand exactly how the exists? method works in activerecord. I am getting some weird results that I don't understand... I am going to simplify my code here for the sake of clarity.

Imagine I have a User model with a list of users.

1 Andy, m
2 Jake, m
3 Cathy, f
4 Mike, m

I have a scope for male, so:

```
User.male => [#< User id: 1, name: Andy, gender: male>, #< User id: 2, name: Jake, gender: male>, #< User id: 4, name: Mike, gender: male>]
```

OK. now:

```
a = User.find 1 => #<User id: 1, name: Andy, gender: male>  
b = User.find 2 => #<User id: 2, name: Jake, gender: male> 
c = User.find 3 => #<User id: 3, name: Cathy, gender: female> 
d = User.find 4 => #<User id: 4, name: Mike, gender: male> 

User.male.exists?(a) => true  
User.male.exists?(b) => true  
User.male.exists?(c) => false  
User.male.exists?(d) => true
```

Ok that makes sense. However:

```
User.male.limit(1) => [#<User id: 1, name: Andy, gender: male>]

User.male.limit(1).exists?(a) => true  
User.male.limit(1).exists?(b) => true  
User.male.limit(1).exists?(c) => false  
User.male.limit(1).exists?(d) => true
```

Why does exists?(b) and exists?(d) return true? Is it because the limit doesn't actually change the query which is still all male users, and limit(1) is simply a display thing? I can buy this, but then what would the correct query be if I only wanted exists?(a) to return true, and everything else to return false?

Okay, now this really confuses me completely:

```
User.male.limit(1).offset(1) => [#<User id: 2, name: Jake, gender: male>]  

User.male.limit(1).offset(1).exists?(a) => false
User.male.limit(1).offset(1).exists?(b) => false
User.male.limit(1).offset(1).exists?(c) => false
User.male.limit(1).offset(1).exists?(d) => false
```

Why does everything here return false? I want exists?(b) to return true, and I can't figure out at all why it doesn't. If anyone can enlighten me, I would be very grateful. I looked through the docs to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User.male` adds a where clause "gender = male"

`.exists?(a)` adds an extra clause "id = 1"

`limit 1` just adds a `limit 1` after the where clause.

So `User.male.limit(1).exists?(a)` will generate 
`SELECT 1 FROM`users`WHERE`users`.`id`= 1 AND (gender =`male`) LIMIT 1`

So the reason why `.exists?(x)` works is because it adds the id to the where clause and thus selects the relevant record.

Also the `offset(1)` wouldn't work because you only get 1 matching record when you put the `exists?(x)` and adding an offset(1) to that would mean that it should look for records after that one.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense to me. So given this, is there a way I can create a query (or method) to get the answers that I want? I want to look through the result of the activerecord relation, and see if a record is inside it.

Comment: Actually I found something that works. If I take the ar:relation and change it to an array, then I can use include?  so: User.male.limit(1).offset(1).to_a.include?(x) gets me the right result. Is this the best way to do this or is there an SQL/other way that is more efficient?

Comment: Also, I just read that Set's include? is faster than Array's, so I've changed it to User.male.limit(1).offset(1).to_set.include?(x)... Maybe there's still a faster way with SQL and/or maybe to_a is faster than to_set, and there is no performance benefit. Anyway....

Comment: If you're trying to figure out if x is a male then you should do `User.male.exists?(x)`. If you just need to find out if x is in a query result, you could do something like `User.male.include?(x)` but from an sql point of view the first method is a lot more efficient.